# PrintForm (from VB Powerpack 3.0) makes all controls black

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to print out a form in my program using PrintForm, however every control on the form appears [black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De6uv.jpg). This is my code currently.

```
Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Show()
    Me.Focus()
    printForm.Form = Me
    printForm.Print()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Is it the fact that the form is still drawing that makes all of the controls black? Also, how can I force my program to print horizontally and in grayscale.

Comment: The Load event fires *before* the form becomes visible.  Calling Show() does change that, it was already called.  So sure, you get a printout of the back of the monitor :)  Use the Shown event, call Me.Update(), then you see them all.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Worked perfectly!